# How many ways to put $m$ balls into $n$ bins including empty assignments?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have $m$ balls and $n$ bins. I would like to find the number of all possible combinations of putting the balls into the bins including empty assignments, i.e., a bin maybe empty (see the example below).

For example, for $m=n=2$, I found:

```
1    x    bin 1 contains ball 1, bin 2 contains nothing.
x    1    bin 1 contains nothing, bin 2 contains ball 1.
2    x    bin 1 contains ball 2, bin 2 contains nothing.
x    2    bin 1 contains nothing, bin 2 contains ball 2.
1,2  x    bin 1 contains balls 1 and 2, bin 2 contains nothing.
x    1,2  bin 1 contains nothing, bin 2 contains balls 1 and 2.
1    2    bin 1 contains ball 1, bin 2 contains ball 2.
2    1    bin 1 contains ball 2, bin 2 contains ball 1.
x    x    bin 1 contains nothing, bin 2 contains nothing.
```

So, I got $9$ combinations.

For $n=2$ and $m=3$, I got $27$ combinations. Thus, I suppose there  are $$(n+1)^m,$$ combinations.

How to prove this? Is this known somewhere?

**Another Problem:** Suppose now we have an additional constraint: each ball can go to only a subset of the bins, i.e., ball $i$ can be put into bins $S_i\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. How many ways to assign the balls into the bins $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_m$ including empty assignments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have wanted to word the question a bit more clearly. We're not *quite* counting the number of ways to put $m$ balls into $n$ bins, because, judging by your example, we allow for the possibility that a ball does not end up in a bin at all.

We can identify each way of doing this as a function $f:[m] \to [n] \cup \{\varnothing\}$ where $f(k) = j$ iff ball $k$ is in bin $j$, and $f(k) = \varnothing$ if ball $k$ does not end up in a bin. This works out to $|[n] \cup \{\varnothing\}|^{|[m]|} = (n+1)^m$.

**Edit**: to address your second question, the answer is simply $$\prod_{i=1}^{m} (1 + |S_i|)$$ by a straightforward combinatorial argument. Namely, for each ball $i$ we have $1 + |S_i|$ choices, including the empty assignment.